# Filechooser component in Walk GUI Toolkit for GO

Tags: user-interface, go

There should be a FileChooser component in the [walk GUI Toolkit](https://github.com/lxn/walk), but I am unable to find it. Can someone point me to the right class?

Comment: Should I delete the question?

Comment: rephrased the question, feel free to accept the answer if it actually was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the SDK documentation, the commondialogs.go of the walk toolkit supplies a FileDialog:
https://github.com/lxn/walk/blob/master/commondialogs.go

(search for "FileDialog" to find the struct)